# Converting Video to mp3 node.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying below code. can anyone tell me whats wrong in the code

```
     var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

     var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample 

     Videos/Wildlife.wmv', nolog: true })

     proc.setFfmpegPath("C:\\nodejs\\ffmpeg")


     .toFormat('mp3')

     .on('end', function() {
     console.log('file has been converted successfully');
     })
     .on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
     })
     // save to file <-- the new file I want -->
     .saveToFile('C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.mp3');
```

C:\nodejs>node test.js
an error happened: spawn C:\nodejs\ffmpeg ENOENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got no file or directory error. on windows platform it needs absolute path

Try below code

```
var os = require('os'); // add at top

var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

     var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample 

     Videos/Wildlife.wmv', nolog: true })

     if(os.platform() === 'win32'){
         proc.setFfmpegPath("C:\\nodejs\\ffmpeg.exe")
     }else{
         proc.setFfmpegPath("C:\\nodejs\\ffmpeg") // change it for linux
     }


     .toFormat('mp3')

     .on('end', function() {
     console.log('file has been converted successfully');
     })
     .on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
     })
     // save to file <-- the new file I want -->
     .saveToFile('C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.mp3');
```

Comment: Hi, @nivas, Should I install the **fluent-ffmpeg** for global?